# Create typings for nested namespaces in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create typings definitions for already existed library, and having issues describe its structure properly. The problem is nested namespaces. In JavaScript full name of my method looks like this:

```
NameSpace1.NameSpace2.NameSpace3.MethodName()
```

But I'm not able to create proper `d.ts` definition file... I've tried different combinations, with `export interface`, `export module` for nested namespaces... But nothing works. The only construction that does not fire any errors is following:

```
declare namespace NameSpace1 {
}
```

But this is not enough... Do you know how to properly describe such a nested namespaces in TypeScript definitions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
declare namespace NameSpace1.NameSpace2.NameSpace3 {
  function MethodName(): void;
}
```

There are literally thousands of examples of how to write definition files at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped ; I'd recommend looking for something similar to what you have next time you're stuck.

Comment: I've tried that approach as well... It didn't worked for me. When I try to use the definition it says: `Property 'Namespace2' does not exist on type 'typeof Namespace1'`...

Comment: It works in the TypeScript Playground. Maybe post an actual example in your question?

Comment: Yes, I will post it right now! Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Yes, you was right. Visual Studio code stuck with old definitions, and was showing errors that does not exist anymore... I've accepted your answer! thank you so much!