# Deeply nested export in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

Is there a way to export nested **types** in typescript without using submodules (e.g. `import "my-package/a"`)?

Like this:

```js
import { A, X } from "my-package"

function a(a : A) {}
function b(b : A.B) {}
function c(c : A.B.C) {}

function x(x : X) {}
function y(y : X.Y) {}
function z(z : X.Y.Z) {}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but you can export the functions directly?
`export {a, b, c}`

Comment: I don't need functions... I need types `A`, `B`, `C`, `X`, `Y`, `Z`.
And I need them as `A.B`, `X.Y.Z` and so on.

Comment: You can't nest types themselves, but look into namespaces (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html).  Here's a way to do nesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38707036/2740650

Comment: Namespaces and various aggregate exports are an option but you are creating an awful API. You are making life harder for everyone including yourself. Follow standard idioms

Comment: Why awful? Is it so nice to have everything in global scope like `Ford` + `FordEngine` and `Toyoya` + `ToyotaEngine`? Why not to use nesting to be able to write `Toyota.Engine` and `let { Engine } = Toyota`?